# Paypal adaptive payment MPL application not authorized (-1)

Tags: paypal

I have been running with Paypal MPL on my Android & iOS app for some time, but for some time now, I have following error:

> "application not authorized" (error code -1)

when I try to execute the pay method (payPalMPL.pay) to display the Paypal screen to make the actual payment.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

MPL has been sunset. Merchants actively using this product were notified in June, 2018.
[Link](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/65#issuecomment-410891366)